# error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ... to an rvalue of type ... when initializing an SimpleActionClient obj in .h file

Tags: c++, ros

I recently developed a ros pkg, I want to initialize an action client object as a member var in head file, so that I can use it in different member functions.

Here is the code in .h file:

```cpp
    actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction> move_planner_
        = actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction>("move_base", true);
```

Here is actionlib::SimpleActionClient implementation:

```cpp
template<class ActionSpec>
class SimpleActionClient
{
    ...
  SimpleActionClient(const std::string & name, bool spin_thread = true)
  : cur_simple_state_(SimpleGoalState::PENDING)
  {
    initSimpleClient(nh_, name, spin_thread);
  }
...
}
```

But compiler give me error:

```sh
 error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction_<std::allocator<void> > >&’ to an rvalue of type ‘actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction_<std::allocator<void> > >’
         = actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction>("move_base", true);
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I don't understand why `actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction> move_planner_` turn out to be a rvalue.

Comment: Which compiler?

Comment: @kiner_shah catkin_make which i think use g++

Comment: In `actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction> move_planner_
= actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction>("move_base", true);`, `move_planner_`  is a non-const lvalue, and the right side of the assignment is an rvalue. That should be allowed. I would understand the error if the code was using `actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction>& move_planner_` (notice the &), which is actually a non-const lvalue reference, and thus cannot be binded to an rvalue. Was the compiler error actually referring to the line in the header file you posted?

Comment: This is basically what that error is telling you: https://godbolt.org/z/M4f4b4vsK. Since the right hand side of the assignment is a temporary, it makes no sense to assign it to a reference you can later modify (non-const lvalue reference); you can either assign it to an lvalue, or to a const lvalue reference, or to an rvalue reference.

Comment: @rturrado Yes, error does refer to the line as i posted(there is no `&`). And if I change it to `actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction> && move_planner_ = actionlib::SimpleActionClient<move_base_msgs::MoveBaseAction>("move_base", true);`, compiling succeed.

Comment: And vscode c++ extension show problem: " no appropriate default constructor available" in this line

Comment: Can you post the complete code for `SimpleActionClient`?

Comment: https://github.com/ros/actionlib/blob/melodic-devel/include/actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h

Comment: Thanks! And your header file, too, please?

Comment: frontier_exploration.hpp https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZVBkk9daPoJNSnIQg9VWIHKOBkxYmNzS?usp=sharing